# How to overload operators with Complex Numbers and Polymorphism?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have to create a Complex class and a vector class that includes vectors of Complex numbers. I have to overload +,-,/,*, << in both classes. Would they both be member functions or would it be easier to put them as nonmember functions? In addition, is there a way to make the vector class only have the vector as a parameter, rather than including the real and imaginary number and vector? The following code from is my class member functions of the vector class.

```
class ComplexVector : public Complex //vectors whose elements are complex numbers
{
public:
  ComplexVector(); 
  ComplexVector(double real, double imaginary, std::vector <Complex> vec); 
  ComplexVector(std::vector <Complex> vec); 
  friend ComplexVector operator+ (const ComplexVector& v1, const ComplexVector& v2);
  friend ComplexVector operator- (const ComplexVector& v1, const ComplexVector& v2);
  friend ComplexVector operator* (const ComplexVector& v1, const ComplexVector& v2);
  friend ComplexVector operator/ (const ComplexVector& v1, const ComplexVector& v2);
  int get_size() const; 

private:
  std::vector <Complex> cvec;

};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const ComplexVector& comvec);
```

I put the explanations of each function in a separate cpp file. Even though I used friend in the header file, on the cpp file it says that i am not allowed to use two parameters. Is there a way to get out of that? In addition, would I have to use pointers in order to access what is in the vector? I have heard of using vector  but I have tried and the arithmetic doesn't make sense to me. (Note: I was playing around so not all the code is exactly correct) Thanks!

```
ComplexVector::ComplexVector() : Complex() {}
ComplexVector::ComplexVector(double real, double imaginary, std::vector<Complex> vec) : Complex(real, imaginary), cvec(vec) {}
ComplexVector::ComplexVector(std::vector<Complex>vec) {cvec = vec;}
ComplexVector& ComplexVector::operator+ (ComplexVector v1, const ComplexVector& v2)
{
  std::vector <Complex> add;
  for (int i = 0; i < v1.get_size(); i++)
  {
    double xside = v1[i].get_real() + v2[i].get_real();
    double yside = v1[i].get_()imaginary + v2[i].get_imaginary();
    add[i] = Complex(xside,yside);
  }
  ComplexVector add_sol(add);
  return add_sol;
}
ComplexVector ComplexVector::operator- (const ComplexVector& v1, const ComplexVector& v2)
{
  std::vector <Complex> sub;
  for (int i= 0; i < v1.get_size(); i++)
  {
    sub[i] = v1[i] - v2[i]; //same as +?
    //does not provide subscript operator????
  }
  ComplexVector sub_sol(sub);
  return sub_sol;
}
ComplexVector ComplexVector::operator* (const ComplexVector& v2)
{
  ComplexVector multi;
  for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
  {
    multi[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
  }
  return multi;
}
ComplexVector operator/ (const ComplexVector& v2)
{
  ComplexVector div;
  for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
  {
    div[i] = v1[i] / v2[i];
  }
  return div;
}
int ComplexVector::get_size() const
{
  int total;
  for (int i = 0, i < cvec.size(); i++)
  {
    total++;
  }
  return total;
}
std::ostream& ComplexVector::operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const ComplexVector& comvec)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < comvec.size(); i++)
  {
    stream << comvec[i] -> get_real() << " " << "+" << " " << comvec[i] -> get_imaginary() << "i" ;
  }
  return stream;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for a complex number vector to be a complex number.

Comment: A friend function is not a member. Get rid of `ComplexVector::` on the function definitions.  Your `operator+` doesn't match the friend declaration and returns a reference to a local variable, which will be dead before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

### Operators defined in the class:

If a class declares the operator + as follow:

```
class A {
public: 
    A operator+(A b);
};
```

It means that the b is the second operand, the first being the object on which the operator is invoked.  Otherwise said, with x, y and z being of class A:

```
z = x + y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
z = x.operator+(y);
```

Unfortunately the `ComplexVector::` in the following definition indicates that you are defining the operator as class member:

```
 ComplexVector& ComplexVector::operator+ (ComplexVector v1, const ComplexVector& v2)
```

The thing is that operator+ takes two operands.  In this case it'll be  the object itself and v1.  So the compiler complains about the second argument that is explicitly declared, which would be the third operand of operand+.  which is illegal.

### Friend operators defined outside the class

If you define a friend operator like:

```
class A {
public: 
    friend A operator-(A a, A b);
};
```

it means that the operator- is not a class member but an independent operator.  As such it needs two arguments for an operation to occur.  So

```
z = a - b;
```

would be equivalent to

```
z = ::operator- (a, b);
```

Unfortunately you do not use that approach in your code.

### Other remarks

You need to declare the operators according to some general rules, so that they keep a semantic of the natural operators.

As such for +, -, * and / you should not take arguments by reference (or eventually a const reference) and you should always return by value, including for operator+.

Here [a step by step article by Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/) to explain more in details some constraints around operator overloading.  Here a [more advanced guideline](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html).

Finally, without wanting to be rude, what's the logic of making a vector of complex inherit from a complex ?  A vector of complex is not a kind of complex.  It's a completely different class, with a dependency relationship, but there's absolutely no justifiable reason for the inheritance ! Or is there ?